# Функция strtok() изменяет значение строки после повторного вызова

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, strtok

Почему при попытке сделать такую программу: *даны две строки, нужно вытащить из них по первому слову*, используя одну и ту же временную строку, в итоге я получаю два одинаковых слова?
То есть, у меня есть две строки `no qwerty` и `yes qwerty`, и я хочу вытянуть из них по первому слову, используя временную строку `tmp`. Для этого я каждый раз копирую содержимое двух строк во временную и произвожу действия над ней.

```
char str[] = "no qwerty";
char str1[] = "yes qwerty";
char *tmp = new char[30];

strcpy_s(tmp, 30, str);
char *a = strtok(tmp, " ");

strcpy_s(tmp, 30, str1);
char *b = strtok(tmp, " ");

cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl;
```

В итоге я хочу получить такие две строки:
`no
yes`
А получаю
`yes
yes`
Насколько я понял, почему-то после работы с второй строкой изменяется строка `a`, которая отвечает за первое слово первой строки.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: В с++ строка - это [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), а не то что вы тут понаписали.

Comment: @zed В C++ также используются C-строки.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow для обратной совместимости. В вопросе от С++ только `cout`, так что, либо тег изменить, либо в ответе писать код на С++, а не гибрид бульдога с носорогом.

Comment: @zed Нормальный код. Используется символьный массив. Почему бы и нет?

Comment: У вас на самом деле три временных строки. Хотя можно было бы обойтись двумя.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Это нормальный код, для программы, написанной на Си.

Comment: @zed Массивы - это агрегированные типы данных в C++. Почему их не использовать?! Те же строковые литералы представляют собой символьные массивы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете в качестве результата два указателя на одну и ту же позицию в строке `tmp`. Поэтому то, что в этой строке на текущий момент находится, то и выводится с помощью этих указателей.

На самом деле нет необходимости для этой задачи использовать функцию `strtok`. Вы можете определить позицию и размер первого слова в строке используя такие функции как `strspn` и `strcspn,` например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char str[]  = "no qwerty";
    char str1[] = "yes qwerty";
    const char *delimiter = " \t";

    size_t n1 = strcspn( str, delimiter );
    size_t n2 = strcspn( str1, delimiter );

    std::cout.write( str, n1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout.write( str1, n2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
no
yes
```

Comment: То есть, для реализации такой программы мне следует использовать вторую временную строку?

Comment: @BorisMakhlin По крайней мере так, хотя на самом деле нет никакой необходимости иметь дополнительные символьные массивы для выделения первого слова в строке.

Answer (score 1):

В чём ошибка, уже указали в ответе выше. А я просто приведу пример, как это можно сделать намного проще, если вам доступен С++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1("no qwerty");
    string s2("yes qwerty");

    cout << s1.substr(0, s1.find(' ')) << endl;
    cout << s2.substr(0, s2.find(' ')) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых для функции `strtok` вызовы кроме первого должны происходить с первым аргументом равным нулевому указателю, то есть, например:

```
char s [] = "abc def";
```

при вызове

```
printf ("%s\n", strtok (s, " "));
printf ("%s\n", strtok (s, " "));
```

выведет

```
abc
abc
```

а вот при вызове

```
printf ("%s\n", strtok (s, " "));
printf ("%s\n", strtok (nullptr, " "));
```

выдаст

```
abc
def
```

Если же нет желания портить строку, то можно воспользоваться функциями `strspn` и `strcspn` (их можно найти в 'string.h') для поиска пробельных символов. Тогда код вывода первого слова мог бы выглядеть так:

```
void printFirstWord (const char * s) {
    const char * ptr = s + strspn (s, " ");
    printf ("%.*s\n", strcspn (ptr, " "), ptr);
}
```